# How to divide a double into whole integers in java?

Tags: java, math, casting, primitive-types

Ok, so I have the following problem, best explained by a concrete example.

Given a double, x (say 100.5), and an int y (say 3), how do I split this up into (roughly equal) parts and return a List containing 33, 33 and 34.5.

I want all the elements in the list to be integers (whole numbers) except for the last one.

Current code:

```
private List<Double> splitIntoApproxEqualParts(double number, int numParts) {
    List<Double> result = new ArrayList<Double>();
    if (numParts <= 0) { return result; }
    double qty = Math.floor(number / numParts);
    for (int i = 0; i < numParts - 1; i++) {
        result.add(qty);
    }
    result.add(qty + 1);
    return result;
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work for cases where numParts < number and other cases too.

What's the most elegant way to do this?

Comment: Given the answers below, and their discussion, it appears that this problem isn't properly defined and your solution is only one of many. I've voted to close this because it's unclear what the behaviour is that is really needed. I suspect that you don't know yourself.

Comment: Roughly equal wasn't clear - all numbers in the list, except for the last one, should be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you almost have a complete solution, add a handler for 1 part and then use your existing `qty` (but subtract it from the original `number` for the last entry). Something like,

```
private static List<Double> splitIntoApproxEqualParts(double number, int numParts) {
    if (numParts <= 0) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    } else if (numParts == 1) {
        return Arrays.asList(number);
    }
    List<Double> result = new ArrayList<>(numParts);
    double qty = Math.floor(number / numParts);
    int t = numParts - 1;
    IntStream.range(0, t).forEach(x -> result.add(qty));
    result.add(number - (qty * t));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Is correct, because `0` is the nearest **whole integer** that can fit in `8` slots (8 * 1 is 8, which is greater than `5` - unless we can also use negative numbers).

Comment: Why not `[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]`? There are multiple valid answers within the given parameters.

Answer (score 0):

How about using

```
public BigDecimal setScale(int newScale, int roundingMode)
```

and for all cases set scale to zero and rounding down.

Then loop through all and keep a running total which can be `diff'd` and added to the last number

Comment: @Thilo I would argue that the first 8 (out of 9) slots are not only "Roughly equal" but are equal

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not so far,

```
private List<Double> splitIntoApproxEqualParts(double number, int numParts) {
List<Double> result = new ArrayList<Double>();
if (numParts <= 0) { return result; }
double qty = Math.floor(number / numParts);
for (int i = 0; i < numParts - 1; i++) {
    result.add((int)qty);
}
qty = (result.get(1))*(numParts-1);
result.add(number - qty);
return result;
```

}

And for the case where numParts >= number, you can add a condition:

```
    private List<Double> splitIntoApproxEqualParts(double number, int numParts) {
List<Double> result = new ArrayList<Double>();
if (numParts <= 0) { return result; }
if(numParts >= number){
    for( int i =0; 1 < number; i++){
        result.add(1);
     }
    for( int i =0; 1 < numParts - number; i++){
        result.add(0);
     }
     return result;
}
else{
    double qty = Math.floor(number / numParts);
    for (int i = 0; i < numParts - 1; i++) {
        result.add((int)qty);
    }
    qty = (result.get(1))*(numParts-1);
    result.add(number - qty);
    return result;
}
```

}

Try it and say me if it's okay !

EDIT
Sorry I failed on an easy calcul, but it's okay now

Comment: So for example, 9/4 gives you:
[2,2,2,3]
And 4/9 gives you:
[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]

Answer (score 0):

Same solution as already posted here, but shorter:

```
private List<Double> splitIntoApproxEqualParts(double number, int numParts) {
    if (numParts == 0) return Collections.emptyList();
    final Double[] result = new Double[numParts];
    Arrays.fill(result, Math.floor(number / numParts));

    // add remainder to the last number
    result[numParts - 1] += number % numParts;
    return Arrays.asList(result);
}
```